# How to enable the threading feature in the Iron framework?

Tags: multithreading, rust, iron

Does the Iron framework support multithreaded mode? How do I enable & configure it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is enabled by default.

The primary structure in `Iron` is [`Iron`](http://ironframework.io/doc/iron/struct.Iron.html), you can start the server using either the `http` or `listen_with` methods.

For [`http`](http://ironframework.io/doc/iron/struct.Iron.html#method.http):

> Defaults to a threadpool of size `8 * num_cpus`.

For [`listen_with`](http://ironframework.io/doc/iron/struct.Iron.html#method.listen_with): the signature takes a `threads usize` argument:

> Kick off the server process with X threads.

Where I suppose `X` stands for the number of threads passed as argument.